# Unicorn we're sorry but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, digital-ocean

I am getting this error when accessing my Rails app:
"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

I am using the 1 click installer from DigitalOcean, and have no errors in the Unicorn logs. How can I fix this and allow my site to be accessible?

I precompiled my assets with this command:
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to play with compile settings in production.rb environment.

Comment: It would be useful to know what exactly you have changed.

Comment: Hey @njny. This thread is too old. But can You please share what changes to be made in production.rb